# linked list at specified position ,where did i go wrong someone guide me through pls

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am able to create a new node of some values specified but while trying to insert a new node at a specific location in the created, my link gets broken somehow, where did I go wrong.
just in case I've genuinely removed the test case for the linked list being empty.

```
#include<iostream>
struct  node                                                                        //declaring node struct with data and pointer to the node itself
{   
    int data;
    node* next;
};
node* headnode;                                                                     //adding another variable headnode which points to null

void insert(int date ){
    node* newnode= new node;
    newnode->data=date;
    newnode->next=headnode;
    headnode= newnode;
}
void insertatlocation(int location){
    std::cout<<"enter data\n";
    int data;
    std::cin>>data;
    node* newnode = new node;
    newnode->data=data;
    node* prepointer = headnode;
    for (int i=0;i<=location;i++){
        prepointer=headnode;
        headnode= headnode->next;
    }
    prepointer->next=newnode;
    newnode->next=headnode;

}
void printnode(){
    node* pointer= headnode;
    while (pointer!=NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<pointer->data<<"->";
        pointer= pointer->next;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    
}

int main(){
    node* headnode=NULL;
    int x,loc;
    int data;
    std::cin>>x;
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        std::cin>>data;
        insert(data);
        printnode();
    }
    std::cout<<"enter the location to add inbetween \n";
    std::cin>>loc;
    insertatlocation(loc);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printnode();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You're modifying `headnode` in your location-insert function. That should only be required when changing the head of the list itself. E.g. `headnode= headnode->next;` has no business being in that loop.

Comment: I reckon clean up the code a bit. too much data leak, do delete the pointers at some point.

Comment: Note: the global `node* headnode;` and the `node* headnode=NULL;` in `main` are not the same variable. Your functions are operating on the global `headnode`. Fortunately, global `headnode` is automatically [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) for you so you probably won't see any ill effects.

Comment: Also in the same loop you keep resetting prepointer to headnode. You also do not check that the location is within the list so you can try to insert beyond the end.

Comment: With a linked list you cannot insert a new node at location if the preceding locations do not yet exist. If you want to add an item at 4 and there is no item 3, you'll either have to return an error code to the caller and refuse to take action or create an item 3. But what value would this wholly-fabricated item 3 have? Best to refuse to insert and return an error message.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh I get it now

Comment: @JoonrooTaugh sure